# Extjs 5 getPlugin doesn't work for grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, plugins, extjs5, celleditingtemplate

How to get access to grid cellediting plugins to call startEditbyPosition to put a particular cell in editing mode. I am using Extjs 5

I have tried below code but getPlugin doesn't work as mentioned in docs for grid.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#...Ext.grid.Panel

```
var field = button;
debugger;
var gridpanelbidding = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('biddinggridpanel1')[0];
console.log(this);
                        var plugin = gridpanelbidding.getPlugin('biddingcelledit'); //this returns null
                        plugin.startEditByPosition({ row: 0, column: 3 });


if (field.getWidgetRecord) {
    var rec = field.getWidgetRecord();
    if (rec) {
        console.log(rec);
        //rec.set('descriptio', field.getValue());
    }
    }
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getPlugin` works if you define `pluginId` property for plugin, not `id`. You can also find your plugin in `grid.plugins` array.

Here is fiddle showing `getPlugin` in work: http://jsfiddle.net/95a1c92f/2/

Comment: Thanks, Can you just point out what is wrong that i am doing in the fiddler, i have the pluginId  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/e7e

Comment: The problem in your code is that in `actioncolumn` handler first argument is of type `Ext.grid.View` not `Ext.grid.Panel`. Grid is available via `view.panel`. I've also changed back plugin type from rowediting to cellediting. See fixed fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/e7m